# How does curl work when loggin to a website

Tags: curl

The following code does not login to the site any positive suggestions:I tried to login but it does not log me in.

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.mywholesaleroute.com/");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);  

$post_array = array(  
'pre_url'=>'jewelry/',  
'login_email'=>'developer1950@gmail.com',
'login_pswd'=>'help99123',   
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array); 

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` the data is encoded as `multipart/form-data`, which the website is not ready to handle at all. Pass in a URL-encoded string:

```
$fields = array();
foreach ( $post_array as $key => $value )
    $fields []= urlencode( $key ) . '=' . urlencode( $value );
$fields = implode( '&', $fields );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
```

This will encoded the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I used this and it worked thanks  for the response soulseekah      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");